# Route with additional query parameter if matches condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'll try to be brief.

I have a rails 4 products catalog and I want provide the user an option to set if he wants to see products with or without stock by default.

My approach to show products with or without stock is by a query parameter, so I have an URL like this to show earphones with stock:

```
http://localhost:3000/categories/earphones?sto_with_stock=t
```

And this one for those with no stock:

```
http://localhost:3000/categories/earphones
```

So my question is: is there a way to set that additional query param in the routes file, if the user matches the condition? I want to avoid changing the URL in every single link_to function. Also, I need to keep my filtering schema untouched.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Both your URLs points to the same controller action. The reason you can see the params in the url is because, it is a GET request. If you want two seperate URLs , declare another method and define another route to the same.

Comment: I think I didn't make my point. What I want, is to set a checkbox for the user who says something like "Show always product in stock by default". So, everytime the user calls a route, i.e. search, show, categories, it adds the ?sto_with_stock=t in the route without having to search for all link_to statements and adding the query params.

Comment: The checkbox will return a value to the controller right, use that as a flag and set the ?sto_with_stock=t in the controller action .

Comment: Thanks, but still I'm being missunderstood, it seems my english is not good enough to make my point clear.

Comment: I dont if it will be of any use to you, but there is a feature called [route constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints) .  You can use it for simple URL validation.